# User with an organization role doesn't get notified nor assigned task

Tags: liferay

I have the next workflow:

An user fills in some fields configured in Dynamic Data List and clicks submit.

An user with the role **Petition analyzer** can assign the petition to himself. Then he can do the next three things: resolve it - *notifying the creator about this*, asking for details - *the petition returns to the creator*, forward it to an organization.

The organization, in turn, can resolve the petition or ask for details. 
I have created two users, user1 and user2 who belong to the organization and have the role **Security role**.

Everything works great except the time when the petition analyzer decides to forward the petition to an organization. The task does not appear under "My Workflow tasks" menu for any of the users belonging to the organization. 
*If I assign the "forwarded to an organization" task to a petition analyzer, the petition analyzer receives the task so, I believe, the workflow is correctly created. Or not ... it's your decision to make.*

*The role, users, organization creation I'm worried about. I have created a role "Security role" of type "organization", an organization called "Organization A" and the users: user1, user2 are added to the Organization A and assigned the role "Security role". When I log in as user1 I expect to find the task and be notified about it which does not happen.*

I am waiting for your sugesstions. Thank you.

Here is my workflow:

```
<workflow-definition
xmlns="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.2.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:liferay.com:liferay-workflow_6.2.0 http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-workflow-definition_6_2_0.xsd">
    <name>Petition workflow</name>
    <description>Petition Workflow</description>
    <version>1</version>
<state>
    <name>created</name>
    <metadata>
       <![CDATA[{"xy":[36,51]}]]>
    </metadata>
    <initial>true</initial>
    <transitions>
        <transition>
            <name>sent it to be analyzed</name>
            <target>sent it to be analyzed</target>
        </transition>
    </transitions>
</state>
<task>
    <name>asking for details</name>
    <metadata>
        <![CDATA[{"transitions":{"resubmit":{"bendpoints":[[303,140]]}},"xy":[328,199]}]]>
    </metadata>
    <actions>
       <action>
         <name>reject</name>
         <script>
          <![CDATA[
              Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("denied"), workflowContext);
              Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(Packages.com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants.toStatus("pending"), workflowContext);
          ]]>
         </script>
         <script-language>javascript</script-language>
         <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
       </action>
       <notification>
         <name>Notification creator that the petition was modified</name>
         <template>Petition was modified by ${userName}. Please make the needed changes and resubmit.</template>
         <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
         <notification-type>email</notification-type>
         <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
         <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
       </notification>
    </actions>
    <assignments>
       <user />
    </assignments>
    <transitions>
       <transition>
         <name>Resubmit</name>
         <target>sent it to be analyzed</target>
       </transition>
    </transitions>
</task>
<task>
    <name>sent it to be analyzed</name>
    <metadata>
       <![CDATA[{"xy":[168,36]}]]>
    </metadata>
    <actions>
       <notification>
         <name>Notification petition analyzer that he needs to analyze a petition</name>
         <template>${userName} sent you a ${entryType}.</template>
         <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
         <notification-type>email</notification-type>
         <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
         <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
       </notification>         
        <notification>
         <name>Notification creator, through email, that the analysis is complete</name>
         <template>
          The petition has been analyzed and has the following commentaries: ${taskComments}.</template>
         <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
         <notification-type>email</notification-type>
         <recipients>
          <user />
         </recipients>
         <execution-type>onExit</execution-type>
       </notification>
    </actions>
    <assignments>           
        <roles>
            <role>
                <role-type>regular</role-type>
                <name>Petition analyzer</name>
            </role>
        </roles>
    </assignments>
    <transitions>
       <transition>
         <name>Resolve petition</name>
         <target>approved</target>
       </transition>
       <transition>
         <name>Ask for details</name>
         <target>asking for details</target>
         <default>false</default>
       </transition>
       <transition>
         <name>Forward to an organization</name>
         <target>forwarded to an organization</target>
       </transition>
    </transitions>
</task> 
<task>
    <name>forwarded to an organization</name>
    <metadata>
       <![CDATA[{"xy":[168,36]}]]>
    </metadata>
    <actions>
       <notification>
         <name>Notification user belonging to an organization that he received a task</name>
         <template>${userName} sent you a ${entryType}.</template>
         <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
         <notification-type>email</notification-type>
         <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
         <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
       </notification>         
        <notification>
         <name>Notification creator, through email, when the analysis is completed</name>
         <template>
          The petition has been sent to be analyzed and has the following commentaries: ${taskComments}.</template>
         <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
         <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
         <notification-type>email</notification-type>
         <recipients>
          <user />
         </recipients>
         <execution-type>onAssignment</execution-type>
       </notification>
    </actions>
    <assignments>           
        <roles>
            <role>
                <role-type>organization</role-type>
                <name>Security role</name>
            </role>             
        </roles>
    </assignments>
    <transitions>
       <transition>
         <name>Resolve petition</name>
         <target>approved</target>
       </transition>
       <transition>
         <name>Ask for details</name>
         <target>asking for details</target>
         <default>false</default>
       </transition>           
    </transitions>
</task> 
<state>
    <name>approved</name>
    <metadata>
       <![CDATA[
         {"xy":[380,51]}
       ]]>
    </metadata>
    <actions>
       <action>
         <name>approve</name>
         <script>
          <![CDATA[
              import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowStatusManagerUtil;
              import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;

              WorkflowStatusManagerUtil.updateStatus(WorkflowConstants.toStatus("approved"), workflowContext);
          ]]>
         </script>
         <script-language>groovy</script-language>
         <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
       </action>           
      <notification>
         <name>Notification creator that petition has been approved</name>
         <template>
          The petition has been approved with the following comentaries: ${taskComments}.</template>
         <template-language>freemarker</template-language>
         <notification-type>user-notification</notification-type>
         <recipients>
          <user />
         </recipients>
         <execution-type>onEntry</execution-type>
       </notification>  
    </actions>
</state>
</workflow-definition>
```

Comment: Anybody has any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 1):

I have took while to look for your workflow definition and test it a bit on my local environment. I managed to reproduce same effect. Even all tasks were assigned to right users, notification for organization roles seemed to not working at all.

Here is what I managed to see after some deeper research:

Web Contents edited within another organization (or just another site) than the one connected with role **Security role** makes notifications not working for organization roles.

From other hand if you do following:

1. Enable your workflow definition for given organization (the same which is set to Security role)
2. Create Web Content within given organization (the same as above)

All notifications seems to be working!

This is quite strange since, whole workflow seems to be working, no matter what organization it uses, but notifications seems to be closely related to organization, of processed tasks. This is either a bug or a feature.

**Update**

Check out this pat of code **WorkflowTaskManagerImpl** class:

```
    if ((role.getType() == RoleConstants.TYPE_SITE) ||
            (role.getType() == RoleConstants.TYPE_ORGANIZATION)) {

            List<UserGroupRole> userGroupRoles =
                UserGroupRoleLocalServiceUtil.
                    getUserGroupRolesByGroupAndRole(
                        kaleoTaskInstanceToken.getGroupId(),
                        kaleoTaskAssignment.getAssigneeClassPK());

            for (UserGroupRole userGroupRole : userGroupRoles) {
                pooledActors.add(userGroupRole.getUserId());
            }
```

**kaleoTaskInstanceToken.getGroupId()** is based on groupId which was saved in **kaleotaskinstancetoken** entry. This means, as I have mentioned above:

If you create Web Content in different Organization than the one which is assigned to your organization role, this part of code won't be able to find such role. As consequence no single notification will be send, for this task.

This is either bug and should be fixed by Liferay, or some sort of feature allowing to pass Organization roles to workflow defintion not connected directly with organization.

Comment: Hi, In my case, not only the notifications do not work, bult also the assignment of tasks. As for the solution given, I do not know  how to enable the workflow definition for the organization. Creating Web Content for the organization means in my opinion to add the portlet 'Web Content Display' on its public page. Somehow, the portlet does not appear when I log in as user1 and access the organization's home page. Can you help me, please ?

Comment: Log in using any user having 'Security role'  and the go to  /group/control_panel/manage?p_p_id=153 There should be all tasks, even though there was no notifications sent.

Comment: No, there are no workflow tasks in there. That's the problem, no tasks are being assigned to users having 'Security role'.

Comment: That is why I believe there's a problem with the way I create the organizations and assign the users to them. When I edit an user I have two kinds of roles: Power User (under Regular Roles) and Security Role (under Organization Roles). There is something I do wrong if you say the assignments worked in your case. I have enabled the workflow defintion for my organization by going under the 'workflow configuration' menu on my organization's site and selecting my workflow .

Comment: First of all, your user have to be member any Organization, then you will be able to add organization roles to him. The same relates to site roles, before you will be able to add site role, user has to be member any site.

Comment: Yes, of course. I did that. The user is a member of the organization. @tomic After that I have assigned the Organization role to him. I have made a site for the organization and have enabled my workflow for its site, that means I have selected my workflow for each of the resource that appears under Workflow Configuration menu. Is there anything else I should have done?

Comment: Maybe this is some sort of problem with your Liferay version. Maybe some bugs wasn't fixed in your SP version. Thats the only one come to my mind, since I have tested your workflow, and it seems all worked. I would suggest you to create regular role, assign to user, change this part of your workflow and then see if it works for this role. If yes, then thats for sure problem with organization roles.

Comment: Yes. I have already tested with regular roles and it works. Can you provide  me with some steps describing what to do after creating the workflow xml file? May be I miss configured or bad enabled the workflow... Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77067/discussion-between-carmen-cojocaru-and-tomic).

Comment: I'am sorry but I am not able to find more time, to spend on your case. Hope you will solve it, if so let me know.

Comment: @CarmenCojocaru I was spending my personal time to help solve your case, and didn't get single thank for this. Even though I had to do some work to try reproduce your scenario. I wasn't able to talk on chat due important work yesterday. Now you are telling me I am misleading people phew... Well good luck on solving it on your own then and stop expecting someone will make the work for you.